# How to check records not in two tables for a date in another third table using DB2 sql?

Tags: sql, db2

I have an Employee table having list of employee names with IDs, from this they flow to two tables with below structure :

EMP Table

| ID | EMP_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | BOB |

`create table EMP (ID varchar(20),EMP_NAME varchar(20));`
`insert into EMP values('100','BOB')`

Table 1

| ID | NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | BOB | 01-10-2021 |
| 100 | BOB | 01-11-2021 |

`create table Table_1(ID varchar(20),NAME varchar(20), DATE date);`

`insert into Table_1 values('100','BOB','01-10-2021');insert into Table_1 values('100','BOB','01-11-2021');`

Table 2

| ID | NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | BOB | 01-11-2021 |
| 100 | BOB | 01-12-2021 |

`create table Table_2(ID varchar(20),NAME varchar(20), DATE date);`

`insert into Table_2 values('100','BOB','01-11-2021');insert into Table_1 values('100','BOB','01-12-2021');`

Table Date

| Month | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| Sep | 01-09-2021 |
| Oct | 01-10-2021 |
| Nov | 01-11-2021 |
| Dec | 01-12-2021 |

`create table DATE(Month varchar(20), DATE date);`
`insert into DATE values('Sep','01-09-2021');insert into DATE values('Sep','01-10-2021');insert into DATE values('Sep','01-11-2021'); insert into DATE values('Sep','01-12-2021'))`

I want to refer table table 3 (Date Table) to identify on which date of TABLE 3 record did not appear in TABLE 1 and 2 ( as in given case record having date = 01-09-2021 is the expected output)

Expected Output

| ID | NAME | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | BOB | 01-09-2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to refer table table 3 (Date Table) to identify on which date of TABLE 3 record did not appear in TABLE 1 and 2

If you just want the overall dates that don't appear, you can use `not exists` or `left join`:

```
select d.*
from dates d
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.date = d.date) and
      not exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.date = d.date);
```

This is the question that you are *asking*.  However, your desired results suggest that you want the employee/date combinations that do not appear.  If that is the case, then `CROSS JOIN` the `emp` and `dates` tables and filter out the ones that don't exist.  One approach:

```
select e.*, d.*
from emp e cross join
     dates d left join
     table1 t1
     on t1.date = d.date and t1.id = e.id left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date = d.date and t2.id = e.id
where t1.id is null and t2.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT E.ID, E.EMP_NAME, D.DATE
FROM DATE D, EMP E
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_1 T WHERE T.ID = E.ID AND T.DATE = D.DATE) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_2 T WHERE T.ID = E.ID AND T.DATE = D.DATE)
```